# How to get logged online users?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to get logged users from SharePoint Content Database?

Or in the other hand, What is the best practice to Making `OnLine Logged users` WebPart in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started: [Find Number of Users Currently Logged on to a SharePoint Site](http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site)

Although the blog post is aimed at SharePoint 2007, it should be feasible to make a SharePoint 2010 version of it.